# Can not get names of fields of my Document Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm tring to do a mapping in order to pass some data from the Elastic Search Engine to some Java object, using this `SearchHit.getAt(i).getFields();` to get a `Map<String,SearchHitField>`.

Problem is, I get an empty map, so I have a `null` value on `SearchHitField` (with `adresseField` for example).

This is my code at the moment:

```
SearchResponse response = searchCriteria(client,"001","Actif");
        List<EsClient> esClientList = new ArrayList<EsClient>();
        // get all Hits of response
        SearchHits searchHits = response.getHits();

        for(int i=0;i<response.getHits().getTotalHits()-1;i++) {

            // get fields of response(hits) (fieldName/value)
            Map<String,SearchHitField> responseFields = searchHits.getAt(i).getFields(); 

            // get required field
            SearchHitField adresseField = responseFields.get("Complement_adresse");
            SearchHitField nomField = responseFields.get("Nom");
            SearchHitField prenomField = responseFields.get("Prenom");
            SearchHitField libelleQuartierField = responseFields.get("Libille_quartier");

            System.out.println(adresseField.getValue());


        }
```

Anyone could help me ? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE :

[image]

response debug value
searchHist debug value

[image]

Comment: I would advise you debugging your code, in order to check if: `response` has any actual data, the actual `totalHits` of `searchHits()`, the content of your `responseFields` map.

Comment: about responseFields is empty (see update

Comment: Can't look at pictures at the moment (silly network), I'll be able to help you later on (if no one does meanwhile). :(

Comment: ok thank you for helping